# Why is the Power Apps form getting stuck on "Getting Your Data..." and not updating the data source?

Tags: excel, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, excel-tables, powerapps-modeldriven

I've created a form in Power Apps that when submitted is meant to append an Excel Table. It is in New Form mode and is connected to a data source. Two of the fields are from approved choices though, so I don't know if I did something wrong there.

I have noticed that in the Excel table when I click on the drop down arrow for each field, the values from the form do appear as filter options, but aren't showing up as records in the table.

I have gone through and changed a few things. I changed the data row limit to 2000 since the tables are in Excel, that didn't help. I went through each card of the forma and made sure the data source was correct and I've been scouring the internet for solutions.

Is it possible that my submit button needs more than SubmitForm('Form1')?